# i am to make my javascript keep a random image from my image folder, after writing all the codes the image is not showing and i don't know why

Tags: javascript

```
var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
var diceName = "images/dice" + randomNumber1 + ".png"

document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].setAttribute("src", "diceName")
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: Instead of `Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1` it's simpler to just do `Math.ceil(Math.random()*6)`

Comment: "diceName" is a variable containing the filename; your code currently sets the source to the literal string "diceName" (instead of using the content of the variable).

Comment: yes: `.setAttribute("src", diceName);`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a string literal to src attribute.

remove quotes from "diceName".

```
 document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].setAttribute("src", diceName)
```